# divide sentence string into substrings =< length of longest single word

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typography, photoshop-script

I am a newbie, and have a pile of data strings (sentences). I'm trying to divide each sentence into substrings where each string's length does not exceed the length of longest single word in that sentence, and returning all words in their original sequence with line breaks (Photoshop carriage return, "\r") dividing the substrings, for that sentence. The words in each string are not hyphenated (only full words or groups of words broken at where a space would be*).* Edit: using the maximum characters, up to the longest word's character count... so a line would have 2 or 3 words possibly, up to the length of the longest word.

I've found examples that split and count the array of words, order them by character length, or add line breaks at set characters, all spaces, etc. But none where I know enough to see an easy modification for this outcome. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you ever use php instead, word wrap is done like this, where `16` represents the longest word. Find: `(?:(?:(?>(.{1,16})(?:(?<=[^\S\r\n])[^\S\r\n]?|(?=\r?\n)|[^\S\r\n]))|(.{1,16}))(?:\r?\n)?|(?:\r?\n))` Replace: `$1$2\r`

Answer (score 1):

Using replace you can replace all the spaces with `\n` to get the result.

```js
a = 'This show navigation menu when you scroll up page 0px up (in right-way). But trying to show after 200px (on page scroll-up) means not showing right way want show and hide after 200px when scroll \n up page.'
b = a.replace(/\s{1,}/g,"\n");
alert(b)
```

Comment: Rejith, this is one of the snippets I've already tried to modify. I am not looking for a way to replace all spaces with a return. I am trying to split the sentence into strings that are equal or less in length of characters, than the longest single word of the sentence, but thank you for replying.

Comment: @ReginaS the above code fulfills your requirement. By definition, if you split the string at all spaces the longest substring will be the longest word and all other substrings will be the same length or shorter.  So what else is missing.

Comment: Yes, this script gives me a stack of single words in original order and separated by line breaks. However, I am trying to keep words together on the same line until that line exceeds the length of the longest word. So some lines would have 2 or 3 words with spaces in between them rather than line breaks. I'm trying to create a text block in Photoshop dynamically, which gets converted to a shape and resized to be the largest it can to fill a container. Sorry I wasn't more clear at the start.

Comment: You're looking for a text formatter? Can you give us a before and after example of the string as I'm not sure I follow how you want the line breaks. I recently did a Photoshop text formatter based on total string length - shouldn't be difficult to modify that.

Comment: Thanks Ghoul Fool, 
before string would resemble: "This is a sentence including various word lengths, some extraordinarily long." and after string would resemble: 
"This is a \r
sentence\r
including\r
various word \r
lengths, some \r
extraordinarily \r
long."\r
("extraordinarily" is the longest word, taking up one line, and all other lines are shorter).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.split` with a regex:

```
var a = 'This show navigation menu when you scroll up page 0px up (in right-way). But trying to show after 200px (on page scroll-up) means not showing right way want show and hide after 200px when scroll \n up page.'
var outputArray = a.split(/\s+/);
console.log(outputArray);
```

---

If you want a more direct way:

```
var a = 'This show navigation menu when you scroll up page 0px up (in right-way). But trying to show after 200px (on page scroll-up) means not showing right way want show and hide after 200px when scroll \n up page.'

a.match(RegExp('.{0,' + Math.max.apply(0, a.match(/\w+/g).map(function(l) {
    return l.length;
})) + '}', 'g');
```

ES6:

```
a.match(RegExp(`.{0,${Math.max(...a.match(/\w+/g).map(l=>l.length))}}`), 'g')
```